# Redux / Flux Pattern for Fetching Data When Store Updates

Tags: redux, flux

I have what I believe is a very common scenario... I'm building a dashboard of components that will be driven by some datasource. At the top of the view would be a series of filters (e.g. a date range). When the date range is updated, the components on the screen would need to update their data based on the selected range. This would in turn force the individual components that are slave to  that picker to need to fetch new data (async action/XHR) based on the newly selected range.

There can be many components on the screen and the user may wish to add/remove available displays, so it is not as simple as always refreshing the data for all components because they may or may not be present.

One way I thought to handle this was in the action dispatched when a new date range is selected was to figure out what components are on screen (derived from the Store) and dispatch async actions to fetch the data for those components. This seems like a lot of work will go into the DATE_CHANGED action.

Another alternative might be to detect date range changes in store.subscribe() callbacks from each of the components. This seems to decouple the logic to fetch the data from the action that caused this to happen. However, I thought it was bad practice (or even an error) to dispatch while dispatching. Sure I can wrap it in a setTimeout, but that feels wrong too.

Third thing that came to mind was just doing fetch calls directly in the component's store.subscribe() and dispatching when those return, but I thought this breaks the connect model.

This seems like a common pattern to fetch based on state changes, but I don't know where its best to put those. Any good documentation / examples on the above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `store.subscribe` for this. When `DATE_CHANGED` reaches the reducer it's meant for, simply change the application state (I'm assuming the date range is part of the store somehow). So you have something like `state.rangeStart` and `state.rangeEnd`.

You didn't mention what view rendering library you're using, so I can only describe how this is typically done with React:

- The components know wether they are currently mounted (visible) or not, so redux doesn't need to be concerned with that. What you need is a way to detect that `state.rangeStart` **or** `state.rangeEnd` changed.
- In React there is a lifecycle hook for that (`componentWillReceiveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` in the newest release). In this handler you dispatch async redux actions that fetch the data the component needs. Your view library will probably have something similar.
- The components display some kind of "empty" or "loading" state while you're waiting for the new data typically. So a good practice is to invalidate/clear data from the store in the reducer that handles the `DATE_CHANGED` action. For example, if `state.listOfThings` (an array) *entirely depends on the date range*, you would set it to an empty array as soon as the date changes: `return { ...state, listOfThings: [] }`. This causes the components to display that data is being fetched again.
- When all the async redux actions went through the `REQUEST` -> `SUCCESS`/`FAILURE` cycle and have populated the store with the data, connected components will automatically render it. This is kind of its own chapter, look into `redux async actions` if you need more information.
- The tricky part are interdependencies between the components and the application they're rendering. If two different dashboard components for example want to fetch and render `state.listOfThings` for the current date range, you don't want to fetch this data twice. So there needs to be  a way to detected that 1) the data range has changed but also 2) a request to fetch `listOfThings` is already on its way. This is usually done with boolean flags in the state: `state.isFetchingListOfThings`. The async actions fetching this data cause the reducer to set this flag to true. Your components need to be aware of this and dispatch actions conditionally: `if (props.rangeStart !== nextProps.rangeStart && !nextProps.isFetchingListOfThings) { props.fetchListOfThings(); }`.

Comment: +1. I think the piece that was missing or foreign was the dispatching of actions in componentWillReceiveProps. I was trying to ask the question independent of the view library. I was thinking that a dispatch would still be in progress by the time the async actions have been dispatched in the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle. store updates guaranteed to have finished when this lifecycle gets invoked? Does this break the separation between container and presentational components?